# Automatic instance deriving after declaration

Tags: haskell, typeclass

In Haskell, when defining a data type you can choose to automatically derive
some instances, but can I defer the automatic deriving, perhaps even put it in
another library?

Here is an example:

Automatic deriving in Haskell is a real time saver!

```
module MoneyModule where

data Money = Money Int
  deriving Show
```

Now I wish to use the `MoneyModule`, but I also want a `Read` instance for `Money`:

```
module ExternalModule where

instance Read Money where
  read = error "Can't this be done automatically instead?"
```

But I would really have preferred for it to be derived automatically, which I know ghc could have done if only the MoneyModule author had auto-derived the `Read` instance.

---

I know that:

- It's better to fix the problem in the actual `MoneyModule` by patching it with the missing instance.
- That it's considered bad to have orphan instances. Instance declarations
  are preferably put in the module where either the type class or the data
  type was defined.

In my case I can't follow best practices since the type class is unrelated
to the data type. I doubt that the type class module nor the data type module
wants to hold the instance, so therefore I'm creating a third library because in some
applications you need the instance declaration.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

GHC has the `StandaloneDeriving` extension, with that, you can

```
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
import MoneyModule

deriving instance Read Money
```

derive instances for many classes.

Answer (score 5):

To solve the problem about stand alone deriving, see daniels solution. But as you mentioned in your question, orphan instances is not best practice and ghc will generate warnings. *To surpress the ghc orphan warnings*, you can use the flag `-fno-warn-orphans`. You can also add it to your cabal file:

```
...
library
  exposed-modules: ...
  ...
  ghc-options: -fno-warn-orphans
...
```